# Find lists where 2 elements are duplicates

Tags: list, haskell

I'm looking for a relatively efficient function to solve the following problem:

Given `records :: [[String]]`, I want to find and return all `[String]`s whose first *and* second elements are the same. So given:

```
records = [["Z", "Jay", "$500M"],
           ["Dilla", "J", "$0"],
           ["Z", "Jay", "$600M"], -- Note the different third element
           ["McCartney", "Paul", "like $1B"],
           ["McCartney", "Paul", "like $1B"],
           ["McCartney", "Joe", "$10"]]
```

`dupFind records` should return

```
[["Z", "Jay", "$500M"],
 ["Z", "Jay", "$600M"],
 ["McCartney", "Paul", "like $5B"],
 ["McCartney", "Paul", "like $5B"]]
```

I'm having trouble with the typical method of sort-then-iterate for finding duplicates, because even when the list is sorted by its first element, its duplicate records may not be adjacent.

Comment: You know, you would probably be best off creating a `Record` type with three fields rather than using lists of strings.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: In general I agree, but the data originated from a CSV, and it's for a tiny little script so it wasn't worth setting it all into data

Comment: "Even when the list is sorted, its duplicate records may not be adjacent." What? In what circumstance does sorting the outer list not group together all those elements with identical first and second elements?

Comment: @DanielWagner: You're right. The records I'm working with aren't actually arranged like this (with the first two elements), but I simplified it for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just sort the list by its first two elements?

```
import Data.List(sortBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)

sortBy (comparing (take 2))
```

should do the job.

Comment: amindfv's example specifies a sorted list, but I'd rather use `groupBy` here myself - `groupBy (comparing (take 2)) :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[[a]]]` - then I wouldn't have to detect the end of one group.

Comment: I thought `groupBy` only matched adjacent elements together.

Comment: I don't understand why you would sort.  Maybe to save a few characters?  But `filter (\x -> x !! 0 == x !! 1)` seems awfully clear to me (although it would crash if there were ever empty lists -- but that's why he should use a record)

Comment: It's not checking `x !! 0 == x !! 1`, it's checking `take 2 x == take 2 y`.

Comment: @rampion : `groupBy (comparing (take 2))` doesn't compile. `groupBy` expects an `a -> a -> Bool` as the first argument, while `comparing (take 2)` is of type `a -> a -> Ordering` .